# Ruby on Rails Form_for resource in other file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, modal-dialog, form-for

Well i have a problem with form_for,with gem devise.
before i have it in users/session/new.html.erb

```html
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true , class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

but now i try to this code in a bootstrap modal, in other file, exactly in app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb because i have a button to "Log in".

when i put there ->  undefined local variable or method `resource' for

a solution? or where i need to put this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is defining `resource_name`, `resource` and `devise_mapping` helper methods in ApplicationHelper. Assuming your devise model is called `user`, place the following methods in your application helper:

```
# application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

Comment: @user3486836, then you can mark my solution as answer (green tick). :)